# Why do we use 'new' in pimpl?

Tags: c++

I was looking at how to use pimpl in C++, and I found this piece of code in a tutorial:

```
// In MyClass.h

class MyClassImp;                    // forward declaration of Pimpl

class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass ();
   ~MyClass();

   MyClass( const MyClass &rhs );   // undefined for simplicity
   MyClass& operator=( MyClass );

   void  Public_Method();

private:
   MyClassImp *pimpl_;              // the Pimpl
};

// In MyClass.cpp

#include "MyClass.h"

class MyClassImp
{
public:
   void   Private_Method()  {}  // dummy private function

   int    private_var_;            // a private variable
};

MyClass::MyClass()  :  pimpl_( new MyClassImp() )
{
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
   delete  pimpl_;
}

void   MyClass::Public_Method()
{
   pimpl_->Private_Method();      // do some private work

   pimpl_->private_var_  = 3;
}
```

But I couldn't get my head around with the reason of allocating the MyClassImp in the heap, can't we just use a variable on the stack?

To clarify:

If we put MyClassImp in a separated .h and .cpp file, and included the .h in MyClass.h, and use MyClassImp pimpl_; (without the pointer), wouldn't it achieved the same effect? When there is change of the implementation of MyClassImp, the caller (MyClass) don't need to change and recomplie. (They will still need to relink)

Comment: *Which* stack? The one of `MyClass::MyClass`? That gets destroyed once the constructor finishes. The one of the caller? *You don't know the caller.*

Comment: Are you asking why you have to have `MyClassImp *pimpl_; ` instead of `MyClassImp pimpl_; `?

Comment: To address "on the stack" - within the stack frame of which function invocation would you want to have it? And to address why not use automatic storage duration - the whole point of the exercise is to hide the definition of `MyClassImp`. If it were a direct member, its size (and hence definition) would need to be known.

Comment: If you use a stack variable, then compiler needs to know the size of it i.e the whole definition. With pointer, you can just do forward declaration and compiler wont need to know its actual structure.

Comment: There might be no stack involved in any of this, e.g. if the code was `MyClass *p = new MyClass;`.  It would be better to show in code what alternative you have in mind

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess the OP would not mind `MyClassImp *pimpl_;` but would prefer to initialize it with the address of an object not explicitly dynamically allocated, possibly a private member of `MyClass`. The calling code wouldn't recognize the difference, but of course the whole purpose of the idiom would silently be defeated (because, as the others have pointed out, the compile fire wall has been torn down).

Comment: Apart from the other answers note that, when you only have a ptr, sizeof( MyClass ) is known by caller. The other convention that OP is referring to resembles to me the detail nested class.

Comment: Spinning this further, one could possibly hack something with placement new (using some sufficiently sized amorphous space held by `MyClass`). Did anybody ever try that? [Ah yes: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm .]

Answer (score 5):

The trick of the pimpl-idiom is, that in your header-file only a pointer is used. This means you can use a forward-declaration of the class without actually providing a declaration.

So you might later change your declaration (in the cpp) without affecting your header or other compile-units using your header.

This is especially useful when dealing with libraries.

Comment: If we simply use MyClassImp pimpl_, and put the MyClassImp in a separated files, include MyClassImp.h in MyClass.h, when there is a change to MyClassImp, MyClass.h don't need to recomplie right?

Comment: As long as you only change the implementation of MyClassImp, yes - but if you change the Interface (=header) as well, you need to recompile. With a pointer you are totally free to do whatever you want, since you dont even include MyClassImp.h

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a new due to the pointer.  The pointer exists so you can forward declare (i.e. not include) the definition of Impl.  If you include the definition of Impl in your header, then you expose it to any file that includes it.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that in order to put the impl on the stack, the code needs to know the size of the impl class at the calling site, which means the impl's class definition would have to be exposed. The whole point of the impl is to *hide* the class definition.